# Experiencing unexpected output from Knime Naive Bayes Predictor

Tags: knime

I'm working on a single-class series with knime and the naive bayes learner/predictor set.

[image]

however when I run a prediction on this, the output of the predictor is only ever 0 or 1 and very closely (100%) resembles the value of the other training column (IncidentOnDate) rather than the target variable (NumIncidents2).

I'm new to DM and Knime, so would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction. I would expect to see output that resembles the same probability distribution and I am intending to get to a point where i can forecast the next 30 days based on distribution probability from the previous periods (I have 2500d of data).

Comment: I worked a bit with KNIME, but never with a Naive Bayes Predictor. If it was I who needed to do the job, I would have just used Python inside KNIME to calculate everything that does not work or has better alternatives in Python. But I am proficient in Python enough to do it.

Comment: OK - Thanks - Python - will check that out.

Comment: Hi Mark, I'm not familiar with Knime, but I do know how NB works. Is the second table supposed to be a representation of the distribution in your training set?

Comment: yes, I believe that is how it works.